# In App Purchase Windows Store Apps

Tags: in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps

I used CurrentApp object to perform an In-app purchase in my application. The process worked fine and users successfully purchased different features. I had to give an update for the app, after a few bug fixes. After the update the users that had bought features through in-app purchase are complaining to have lost previously bought features. How does windows store persist the purchases? Do I need to manually store all transaction details within the app as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!App.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[@"UpgradeOption1"].IsActive)       
{              
    // The content of code 
}
else
{
    // Include the upgrade logic
}
```

hope it will helpful to you... Otherwise you can check out [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/ece8960f-1018-4aa1-b48e-58a661d4c833)

and one more great [blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/2b736b3e-e9c9-4b62-8e9f-719906a3cc48..)